# Mysqli Case statement (update) in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, case

```
mysqli_query($tradeL,"UPDATE openor SET cur2 = CASE 
               WHEN $val1e<cur2 THEN cur2-$val1e
               WHEN $val1e>cur2 THEN $val1e-cur2
               WHEN $val1e=cur2 THEN '0'
               ELSE cur2
                WHERE id='2' END");
```

gives the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE id='2' END' at line 7

I just can't see the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end your case first then use where clause

```
UPDATE openor 
    SET cur2 = CASE                
    WHEN $val1e<cur2 THEN cur2-$val1e
    WHEN $val1e>cur2 THEN $val1e-cur2
    WHEN $val1e=cur2 THEN '0'
    ELSE cur2 END
    WHERE id='2'
```

Also you can skip your else part

```
UPDATE openor 
    SET cur2 = CASE                
    WHEN $val1e<cur2 THEN cur2-$val1e
    WHEN $val1e>cur2 THEN $val1e-cur2
    WHEN $val1e=cur2 THEN '0'
    END
    WHERE id='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why overcomplicate things?  Just use MySQL's [`ABS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function:

```sql
UPDATE openor SET cur2 = ABS(cur2 - $val1e) WHERE id = 2
```